# python number in textfiles counting

Tags: python, text-files

i have text files with tags(Korean words) and count numbers.
I'd like to count all the numbers from count from text files.
But it's a quite tough task for me.
It would be great if i get some help...

ex)

```
tag: 있다, count: 61
tag: 맛있다, count: 48
tag: 같다, count: 26
tag: 없다, count: 23
tag: 아니다, count: 20
tag: 좋다, count: 18
tag: 이다, count: 14
tag: 좋아하다, count: 12
tag: 많다, count: 12
tag: 그렇다, count: 11
tag: 유명하다, count: 9
tag: 시원하다, count: 6
tag: 이렇다, count: 6
tag: 멀다, count: 5
tag: 바쁘다, count: 5
tag: 어떻다, count: 5
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: Oh.. i crawled blogs from web and saved it as textfiles. And i would try to count all the numbers, but i have no idea how to start with.

Comment: I repeat: "what have you tried that didn't work ?"  This means : "what have you tried to solve your problem",  "problem" here is being "count all the numbers from count from text files" (whatever this migh actually mean).  How you got that text file is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you read file line by line, then you can split each line:

```
counter = 0
line = row.split(" ") # assumes all the lines are the same as you described
```

Then you have array like this: 
`['tag:', '있다,', 'count:', '61']`

Now each array has 4 elements, and you can always pick the last one.

```
counter += int(line[3])
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pandas` to read your text file into a table:

```
import pandas as pd
#read text file, split with regex seperator
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep = ":|,", names = ["tag", "count"], usecols = [1, 3], engine = "python")
print(df)
```

Output

```
      tag  count
0      있다     61
1     맛있다     48
2      같다     26
3      없다     23
4     아니다     20
5      좋다     18
6      이다     14
7    좋아하다     12
8      많다     12
9     그렇다     11
10   유명하다      9
11   시원하다      6
12    이렇다      6
13     멀다      5
14    바쁘다      5
15    어떻다      5
```

Sum all values in column `count`

```
print(df["count"].sum())
>>>281
```